# How to best store and expose external route based location data for use in views/charts/openlayers?

Tags: views, location, 8, database

I have a large amount of different route data (hundreds of thousands of different location pairs per week and some accompanying data for each pair such as datetime, speed, direction) that I am parsing from raw data files (that are added as files/nodes using REST services) into a mysql db currently, with the plan of exposing this data to views for use in charts and openlayers etc. However, I am wondering if this is the best method and whether I would be better off parsing the data into a different storage system.

What would be your storage method of choice in this scenario? What storage would offer the best read times into views for mapping out large trips containing thousands of data points?